# how to use external js library with Aura?

Tags: javascript, aura.js, aura-framework

I've added

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

in aura:application file, file is downloaded by browser (can see that thru console)
but when i try to create Chart object in afterRender function in Renderer

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { .....
```

I've got an error:

> Something has gone wrong. afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://helloWorld:helloWorld' [afterRender threw an error in
>   'markup://c:ltGraph' [**ReferenceError: Chart is not defined**]] Failing
>   descriptor: {markup://helloWorld:helloWorld} Error
>       at new  (http://localhost:8080/auraFW/javascript/lG7eYFZ_MXfCccXumk95LQ/aura_dev.js:3152:23)
>       at http://localhost:8080/auraFW/javascript/lG7eYFZ_MXfCccXumk95LQ/aura_dev.js:1:1.
>   Please try again.

How to use external libraries in Aura ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. My code wanted to use library before it was loaded.
I have to put some checks in my js code (renderer)

```
var timesToCheck = 10;
var poll = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        timesToCheck--;
        if (typeof Chart !== 'undefined') {

            // now you can use Chart (or other) library.....

        } else if (timesToCheck > 0) {
            poll();
        } else {
            console.log('giving up')
        }
    }, 100);
};
poll();
```

(code taken from https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Amaz )

But still, i have a problem with loading 2 dependent libraries (like jQuery and Flot). Quite often there is an error that jQuery is undefined during a Flot initialization.....

Comment: What version of Jquery is your aura app using. if its 3.x then i would suggested to use 2.2.4 of Jquery as 3.x seems to have issues with the Locker Service Critical update from summer 16 release.

Comment: problem was with trying to use jQuery/Flot before libraries were actually loaded

Comment: Can you let me know what is the error message that you are receiving when trying to load Jquery ..